# git merge to a branch without changes and commit

Tags: git, git-merge

Say I have two branches, `master` and `feature_new`. If `master` and `feature_new` both have different commits on top of them relative to when they branched out, when I do a

```
git checkout master
git merge feature_new
```

I will get a "merge commit" with the commit message `Merge branch feature_new`. But if `master` has no changes on top of it, I won't get this commit. Is there a way to always have a merge commit in this case?

This allows me to see a history of what got branched and which commits got merged from that branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Git will try to fast-forward a branch. Fast-forwarding means that the branch can be moved forward linearly without requiring an actual merge. The most common case where this happens is when your master is outdated and you pull from the remote which has a few more commits.

If you want to force a merge commit, you can do this:

```
git merge feature_new --no-ff
```

`--no-ff` means “no fast-forward” and will avoid fast-forwarding when it’s possible. Thus this will always result in a merge commit even if it wasn’t necessary.

To quote the [manual](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge):

> #### --no-ff
>
> Create a merge commit even when the merge resolves as a fast-forward. This is the default behaviour when merging an annotated (and possibly signed) tag.